# The keyPressed function only fires once for each key in Chrome

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using the P5 library and I want to register key presses. Everything runs as expected on Chrome,Edge and Firefox when the HTML file is opened locally. If I try to host it on github pages it works on Firefox and Edge, but unfortunately not on Chrome. I have tried writing to the console when the keyPressed function detects a key press, which should happen every time a key is pressed, but it only registers the arrow keys once and then ignores they following key presses. Does anyone have a clue about what might be causing this.

```
function keyPressed(){
    if(keyCode === 37){
        MoveLeft();
    }
    if(keyCode === 38){
        MoveUp();   
    }
    if(keyCode === 39){
        MoveRight();    
    }
    if(keyCode === 40){
        MoveDown(); 
    }
    if(gameOver === true){
        ResetGame();
    }
    console.log('keyPressed');
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: to be 100% sure move the `console.log` at the top of the execution

Answer (score 0):

```
var bg = "#333";
var gameover = false;
function draw() {
  background(bg);
}

function keyPressed(){
  if(gameover){return false;}
  if(keyCode === 32){
    bg = "#0000FF";
  }
  return false;
 }

function keyReleased(){
  bg = "#333";
}
```

See https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyCode 
Use http://keycode.info/